# Visual Studio 2017 ASP.Net Debugging Error on Entity Data Model 0x80070057

Tags: asp.net, debugging, web-applications, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

Without changing a thing visual studio started reporting 
"The function evaluation requires all threads to run." on a breakpoint I have in my code
Then when I try to do that I get
"Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057."

I created a new .Net Framework Web Application with a Entity Data Model called EDF and tried to run this simple piece of code, but I get the errors mentioned above

```
            using (EDF ef= new EDF())
        {
            var results = ef.aspnet_Users.AsQueryable();
            Console.Write(results); //break point is here
        }
```

This is really frustrating as I haven't even changed a thing and this error just started occurring, any help would be appreciated thanks.

I am using VS Community 2017 v 15.5.4 and EntityFramework v 6.2.0, Below is the VS output.

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\a8b70205\00584630_5b15d301\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\f5a012c4\002e67fe_d826cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\a234620a\0059594b_e18cce01\Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\afaff7a7\00d3f65b_fb81ce01\AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\898bd686\00ff377e_8eaace01\Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\b339d3bf\001e4278_8eaace01\Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\ddf5ddf7\00814da7_1f9fce01\AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\App_global.asax.wvewwhap.dll'. 
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\ef0a4caa\c561f42a_f893d301\WebApplication2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\6f1bf325\00772af5_1250d201\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\095fc66e\001858d4_654fd201\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\4f37b6cb\002f3079_1250d201\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\6a2df9a4\00d93b27_1350d201\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\e539217c\00d93b27_1350d201\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\13d4f425\006289a8_664fd201\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\234ddee4\009325ea_b64ad201\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Diagnostic message: Performance counters are unavailable when the application is running under IIS Express. Use EnableIISExpressPerformanceCounters element with a value of 'true' within the Performance Collector Module element to override this behavior.
>   Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Message","time":"2018-01-23T04:50:32.7592099Z","tags":{"ai.operation.parentId":"41oe8i/F02k=","ai.operation.name":"GET /","ai.operation.id":"41oe8i/F02k=","ai.operation.syntheticSource":"SDKTelemetry","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"Zissou","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"dotnet:2.2.0-54037"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"AI: Diagnostic message: Performance counters are unavailable when the application is running under IIS Express. Use EnableIISExpressPerformanceCounters element with a value of 'true' within the Performance Collector Module element to override this behavior."}}}
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.ixcl_fya.dll'. 
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\App_Web_site.master.cdcab7d2.7zp2w5-g.dll'. 
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\07640611\002e67fe_d826cf01\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\e8cb0cbd\00a63921_7410ce01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\50f8bd1c\00afb801_944bd301\EntityFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\1f7b83b3\00dce902_944bd301\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\25de16f8\007209aa_f5aecf01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\c8f77fa9\dd3a5d30\assembly\dl3\4ba07377\00071d9a_e6adce01\WebGrease.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\common7\ide\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131611566317271508): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-WebApplication2'.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the “Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls”? under Debug -> Options

Comment: Yes that was already turned on